# Parse data within script tag in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

Trying to parse some data that is included within a  tag in the HTML using JavaScript. Specifically I'd like to retrieve the value for 'email' as in the script below, with the expected output being "your@email.com"

```
<script type = 'text/javascript" nonce>

var _hsq = window._hsq = window._hsq || [];

_hsq.push(["identify",{
    email: "your@email.com",
    firstname: "yourfirstname",
    lastname: "yourlastname",
}]);

</script>
```

Tried using document.querySelector and document.getElementsByTagName to isolate the HTML element, but as there is no unique ID or class for the script tag I'm unable to isolate the specific script in question. I also tried reading from the "_hsq" variable but it didn't return anything.

Comment: You're reading from html, but you didn't include the html! Add it to your post so we don't have to guess. You also say you tried `document.querySelector()` and `document.getElementsByTagName()`, but don't include your attempt here. Let us know fully what you've tried. Your code here has no reference to the html.

Comment: Your HTML has unbalanced quotes. Please fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you're looking for is being attached to the `window` object, so you can retrieve it from there.  You don't need to be looking in the DOM.

```js
var _hsq = window._hsq = window._hsq || [];

_hsq.push(["identify",{
    email: "your@email.com",
    firstname: "yourfirstname",
    lastname: "yourlastname",
}]);


console.log(window._hsq[window._hsq.length-1][1].email)
```

(It's not the cleanest data format ever invented; if that's code you're able to change, you might be better off with a simple object or flat array of objects, instead of an array of arrays each containing a name and an object.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last element of `_hsq` with `_hsq.slice(-1)`, then pull out the email with something like `_hsq.slice(-1)[0][1].email`.